# How to change the picture in the upper right corner in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, user-interface

How to change the picture in the **upper right** corner in Gmail? The solution should work in all the (major) browsers.

[image]

I usually keep opened several Gmail accounts in various tabs at the same time and it would be easier to quickly distinguish them.

I am **not** asking how to change your *profile* picture, I have done that:

[image]

However Gmail still uses just the fist letter of the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the icon that you marked red and click on change. You can upload a picture in the popup or use one that's already in your account.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVcYu.png)

**Edit**
I also had to do a "hard refresh" in Chrome (Ctrl + F5) for the correct image to be displayed after visiting the site again. Before I did that the picture changed after I uploaded it and reset back to the letter on refreshing the page / visiting it again.

Comment: Oh, you mean in Chrome... Yes, actually you are right, it works in Chrome. But not in Firefox :( I have just tried it in both the browsers, before I had not thought about using Chrome. So it *is* an answer, but... I would prefer if it worked in all the browsers...

Comment: I tried it again in Firefox, now it kind of displayed, it changed the profile picture, but it did not survive closing and opening the browser. However, my profile picture keeps being set, so it seems like Goggle has an incompatibility of their app with Firefox,

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an issue with Firefox. I can reproduce it here as well. Chrome and IE are fine while Firefox doesn't work properly. If you want to get it fixed you should contact Google at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail I suppose.

Answer (score -2):

it can be if you use your business account or your school account I also had that problem but I understood it was because of my school account. it  will never let you change your profile pic only if you do your own acount